# Input Field Max Character Limit

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I am adding an input field in my website where user can enter Zip Code. Since Zip Codes have max limit for characters of 5, I want to add a validator or any other mechanism that can stop accepting (disable the input tag kinda) characters after 5.

I tried something like this but to no success:

```
` addValidators() {
    const myFieldControl = this.registrantForm.get('zip_code');

    if (myFieldControl) {
      myFieldControl.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)]);
      myFieldControl.updateValueAndValidity(); // Update the control's state
    }
  }`
```

Comment: Keep in mind that by doing this you're restricting your website to one country only. Other countries have different "Zip Codes", or none at all. See: [List of Postal Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes).

Comment: For now this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the length of text of an input you can use [the maxlength attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength).

```html
<input id="zip_code" maxlength="5">
```

Note that you should never rely on [client-side](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/client-side-vs-server-side) validation of input only, always check it again on the server.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.